# SES Rule to S3 does not trigger SNS notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a SES Receipt rule which redirect emails to S3 and a SNS to SQS as such:

```
resource "aws_ses_receipt_rule_set" "chat-replies" {
  rule_set_name = "${local.deployment-name}-chat-replies"
}

resource "aws_ses_active_receipt_rule_set" "chat-replies" {
  rule_set_name = aws_ses_receipt_rule_set.chat-replies.id
}

resource "aws_ses_receipt_rule" "chat-replies" {
  name          = "${local.deployment-name}-chat-replies-store"
  rule_set_name = aws_ses_receipt_rule_set.chat-replies.id
  recipients    = [local.emails-chat-replies-domain]
  enabled       = true
  scan_enabled  = true

  s3_action {
    bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.chat-replies.bucket
    position    = 1
    topic_arn   = aws_sns_topic.chat-replies.arn
  }

  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket_policy.chat-replies]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "chat-replies" {
  bucket   = "${local.deployment-name}-chat-replies"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "chat-replies" {
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.chat-replies.id
  acl      = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "chat-replies" {
  bucket                  = aws_s3_bucket.chat-replies.id
  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "chat-replies" {
  bucket   = aws_s3_bucket.chat-replies.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSESPuts",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ses.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "${aws_s3_bucket.chat-replies.arn}/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:Referer": "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_sns_topic" "chat-replies" {
  name     = "${local.deployment-name}-chat-replies"
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "chat-replies" {
  name                      = "${local.deployment-name}-chat-replies"
  message_retention_seconds = 604800 # 7 days
  receive_wait_time_seconds = 20     # long poll
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "chat-replies" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.chat-replies.arn
  protocol  = "sqs"
  endpoint  = aws_sqs_queue.chat-replies.arn
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "chat-replies" {
  arn      = aws_sns_topic.chat-replies.arn
  policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sns-chat-replies.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sns-chat-replies" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "SNS:Publish",
    ]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "AWS:SourceAccount"

      values = [
        data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id,
      ]
    }

    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "ses.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    }

    resources = [aws_sns_topic.chat-replies.arn]
  }
}

output "chat-replies-queue-url" {
  value = aws_sqs_queue.chat-replies.url
}
```

While I'm perfectly see emails in my S3 bucket, the SQS queue is empty?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing `aws_sqs_queue_policy`:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue_policy" "chat-replies" {
  queue_url = aws_sqs_queue.chat-replies.id
  policy    = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sqs-chat-replies.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sqs-chat-replies" {
  statement {
    sid    = "First"
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "sns.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    }

    actions   = ["sqs:SendMessage"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any documentation about what topic_arn does inside of the s3_action and it seems odd to me to find it there. Instead, I'd remove it from the s3_action block and add an additional sns_action block with the topic_arn for your chat-replies topic. Something like:

```
resource "aws_ses_receipt_rule" "chat-replies" {
  name = ...
 
  s3_action {
    position    = 1
    bucket_name = aws_s3_bucket.chat-replies.bucket
  }

  sns_action {
    position  = 2
    topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.chat-replies.arn
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually it's described in the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-action-s3.html (at the bottom). The thing is, it does not acknowledge the email storage, but put the email content as your rule does.